# Bash dynamically loadable builtin written in c++ not enablable?

Tags: c++, c, bash

I am writing a loadable builtin called `items` for **bash** using C++ instead of C and wrapped the relevant (interfacing) portions in an `extern "C"` directive. So everything builds fine and I get my shared library `items` ... only trying to enable it results in:

```
$ enable -f ./items items
bash: enable: cannot open shared object ./items: ./items: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0
```

Googling about `__gxx_personality_v0` gave me the hint that the involvement of `libstdc++` is missing - of course.

My question is: Is there an easy and reasonable way to make the loadable enable or do I have to go back to plain C anyways?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just install the missing library?

Comment: as @TheTailgunner asked, can you add the exact command(s) you used to build the shared library ?

Comment: You can try to statically link libstdc++ to your binary, with the gcc option -static-libstdc++

Comment: Did you link it using g++? (You should)

Comment: Thx to all of you! Looking more closely at the linker command i realized that i linked with gcc and compiled with g++. After changing that the '__gxx_personality_v0' problem disappeared. New problems came up concerning differences in name mangling by g++ as opposed to c but i will be able to handle those by using 'extern "C"'.